# How to securely load an image from camera and display it in full size on Android?

Tags: android, security, camera

For security, I was advised to avoid using getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) for storing files and creating insecure temporary files with File.createTempFile.

How can we rewrite this in a secure way?

```java
clTakeBottomSheetCamera.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        try {
            profilePhotoFile = createPhotoFile(tag); // FIXME <--

            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.test.test" + ".provider", profilePhotoFile);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);

            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_PASSPORT_IMAGE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

```java
 private File createPhotoFile(String tag) throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = custPhoneNumber + "_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); // FIXME: Insecure data storage
        File imgFile = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir); // FIXME: Insecure temporary file creation

        profilePhotoPath = imgFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return imgFile;
    }
```

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_PASSPORT_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Display the captured image in an ImageView with Glide
        Glide.with(activity).load(profilePhotoPath).into(ivCustomerPhotoActivation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); // FIXME: Insecure data storage
```

Instead of `getExternalFilesDir()`, use `getFilesDir()` or `getCacheDir()`, and adjust your `FileProvider` metadata to match.

```java
File imgFile = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir); // FIXME: Insecure temporary file creation
```

If you fix the earlier problem, this should no longer be considered to be insecure.

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by "adjust your FileProvider metadata to match"? better if you provide an example. Thanks

Comment: @amo: You are using `FileProvider`. Part of that involves setting up an XML resource file that describes what files `FileProvider` is allowed to provide. Right now, you have a rule set up in that file to support `getExternalFilesDir()`. You will need to modify that file to support whichever new root you choose. See [the `FileProvider` documentation for more](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider).

Comment: @amo: FWIW, I cover `FileProvider` in [this section](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-files-005.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack).